# Gatling can't run simulation

Tags: gatling

I'm using gatling 2.2.3 and I'm following the [Quickstart guide](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.3/quickstart.html). I've got it all working up until the point where I can run the scenario.
Instead of allowing me to select the simulation I want to run I'm getting this output:

```
U:\>%GATLING_HOME%\bin\gatling.bat
GATLING_HOME is set to "C:\Users\name\Downloads\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.3\"
JAVA = "java"
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

It seems like it's trying to execute some Java command which isn't done properly. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Java? If not then download and install Java 8. Also set the java path properly in environment variables.

Comment: I did all of that. I solved the problem by moving gatling to a different folder, not quite sure what was wrong but it works now

Comment: Could you tell us to which directory did you move your files?

Comment: @NakakapagpabagabagHm I'm sorry. I don't remember to what directory I moved some files almost 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

What this folder is:
U:>%GATLING_HOME%

Be sure don't have blank spaces in it